# We have a set S of n potential investments

Tags: sorting, pseudocode, set

We have a set S of n potential investments, each given by a pair of floating point numbers (amount, estimated return) There is a total amount A to invest; we want to select investments to maximise the return on this amount.

please explain how do i order the investments using the ratio estimated return/amount, in nlogn.
is this using quick sort? i can calculate the ratios in O(n) then how do i keep an index as to which ratio belongs to which investment?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a kind of [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)? Usually such kind of problems are solved using dynamic programming. There are [several](http://www.programminglogic.com/knapsack-problem-dynamic-programming-algorithm/) [examples](http://sriwantha.blogspot.ru/2011/07/knapsack-problem-in-c.html) on the web, including the topic [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683066/knapsack-problem-classic?rq=1).

Comment: it sort of is, but i thought we can use an easier algo for this one,
1.start by ordering the investments according to the decreasing ratio r/a
2.allocate available money to the investments in such order. I.e. buy all the first investment, then use available money to buy the second investment, then the third, etc, until you have finished the money.

Comment: am stumped by the sorting part :/