# A recursive algorithm to find and optimum (Somewhat like knapsack)

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I'm supposed to write an algorithm (recursive, and then improve it using dynamic programming) that get's `W`, total weight, and calculates the optimal way to fill the sack (but here's the difference from *knapsack*)  when there are only 3 possible weights.

```
 - weight: 4        price: $1
 - weight: 3        price: $0.7
 - weight: 1        price: $0.2
```

What's the direction you'll go for? I'm not sure on how to think of the *Greedy Algorithm* since if `W = 6` both `4+1+1` and `3+3` will get to the value of $1.4.

Comment: Just to clarify - you need to maximize W (with a limit of 6) while _minimizing_ total price? Or while _maximizing_ price? If two solutions give the same value, you should see whether either of them has a sub-solution that works better (eg change one 3 into 3 1's). Plenty of online help if you look... In the end if two solutions meet the criteria, there are indeed two solutions. Is there not a "with the fewest number" or some such to differentiate them?

Comment: @Floris, I just need to find the optimal load in a matter of value, I don't care about the number of elements in the sack. Which of the knapsack variations I should be looking for? I have a limited number of weights, but the sum of all weights must not exceed W.

Comment: Not sure why you think that "having only three weights" make this different from knapsack problem... I assume there are "more than one" of each weight - in other words, that there is no limit on the number of items as long as their total weight does not exceed W.

Comment: It seems to me that the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683066/knapsack-problem-classic should work for you. If it doesn't please explain why not.